# What is the best website for mass upload of pre-organized photos?

Tags: webapp-rec

If I have a large collection of photos which are already organized into folders and file names, what is the best/easiest way to share these on the web without having to painstakingly re-label / re-tag / re-file every photo?

Ideally, the each folder should automatically become an album, and each filename a caption.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Picasa does that. Try it out. You also have the option of using the Picasa Gdata APIs to automate and customize uploads if you really need to.